# Optimal TCP segment size

Tags: tcp, network-protocols

I've read some articles about TCP Protocols and  maximum segment size, and also on how it is calculated. (this article : [rfc879](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc879))

I'm interested to know is there optimal or default maximum segment size Value for  various protocols such as FTP or Http? if Yes , How can I find them?

tanks .

Comment: Research. We don't like doing research.  Do you have a code or specific design problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly clear from RFC 879. MSS is a property determined either by the receiver or the rules defined therein. If the receiver defines it, it does so during connection negotiation, so there is no opportunity for any application protocol to change it even if it wanted to.

MSS therefore has nothing whatsoever to do with specific application protocols.  Your question therefore doesn't make sense.